# can i use same server for Active Directory and Windows Deployment Service?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2012, wds

I've a problem, can i use same server machine for both Active Directory and Windows Deployment Service. I don't know the steps to do it both can someone please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. It's not really reccomended to run anything else on the DC apart from the Domain Controller and DNS/DHCP Roles, but it's certainly doable. Install the AD Doman Controller role first, then Windows Deployment services.

Note: As you've tagged this with both Server 2008 and 2012 it's worth mentioning that Windows Deployment Services on Windows Server 2012 can be installed "stand alone" (i.e. not connected to a domain). This is in fact what I do at home and use a ProxyDHCP client to offer the PXE Boot functionailty to the clients.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, Microsoft doesn't restrict it, but strongly not recommended. Also, please don't get confused about configuring DHCP server for PXE option (67 DHCP option).

If you decide to go with that, first you instal AD DS role (DNS will install automatically if you are creating new forest), then DHCP role, then WDS role.